# Sending from secondary email account in outlook

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have an excel spreadsheet with some VBA that will send a marketing email to everyone with an email address in a spreadsheet.

When I send it through my main account it works absolutely perfectly but when I try to send it through our 'marketing@' email account, it only sends back **to** that account.

The emails send from my account (correctly) and appear in my sent items and when they are received in the marketing@ account, the reply address is marketing@ so everything appears to be working.  It is just not sending to the recipient.

I have permission to SendAs in Exchange and this works (if I try a different address I get an access denied error message) but cannot work out why this isn't working for me at all.

This is my code:

```
 Private Sub StackOverflow()
  Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set OlApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olMail = OlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With olMail
      .SentOnBehalfOfName = """Marketing"" <marketing@>"
      .To = "Recipient"
      .Subject = "Test"
      .Body = "Test"
      .Display
    End With

  Set olMail = Nothing
  Set OlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

What changes I need to make to this code to get it to send to the recipient and not back to the account I'm sending from?

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Edited to make the code minimal

Comment: The current minimal code will send to "Recipient". It is neither complete nor verifiable. There would be a better than zero chance for an answer if you put just enough code so you see (verify) the problem, with the minimal and now complete example code. Describe how you get "Recipient" in a way others can try to recreate the process.

Comment: That's the problem I'm having.  Although the code should send to the recipient, it doesn't.  It's sending from my regular account (confirmed by being in Sent Items), on behalf of the second account (confirmed by replying straight to the second account) but it's being delivered to the second account (confirmed as it is auto-forwarded to a colleague for verification) and not the intended recipient.

Comment: "Recipient" is incorrect, if the address are on your spreadsheet then loop thru it and add it to the created email

Comment: Recipient is just to hide what are private emails.  It's a genuine, valid email address.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been solved and it's nothing to do with Excel or Outlook.

It seems that somehow, a rule was placed on the server that re-routed anything sent from this account to the account instead.  Now this rule has been removed, the code works perfectly.